# Room Database Query from background Thread

Tags: android, observable, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have read that one of the ways to query data in room database is to use Livedata which can be used on the main thread as it is asynchronous.

I would like to use LiveData instead of RxJava or AsyncTask.

For this in my repository class I have function getSomeData() which returns LiveData> and I call this function in my viewModel constructor:

```
private var mObservableSomeData: LiveData<List<SomeData>>

init {
    mObservableSomeData = repository.getSomeData()
}

fun getSomeData(): LiveData<List<SomeData>> {
    return mObservableSomeData
}
```

However it crashes saying:

> Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

What should I do?

Comment: In your Dao class, are you wrapping the return type of your query in LiveData as well?

Comment: That's what I did :  @Query("SELECT * FROM somedata")
    fun loadAllData(): LiveData<List<SomeData>>

Comment: To which line does the error point exactly? Do you also have an insert query?

Comment: yes I have insert too, yes you are probably right and it's insert that causes crash

Comment: yep, use an AsyncTask like in this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#7), it's in Java though :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by @LieForBananas, most probably you are getting error while doing insertion. Whenever you have @Query and you are wrapping returned data into an observable e.g. LiveData or Flowable, your query gets executed on background thread by default.

Remember that Room Database ensure that the query returning observable is run on background thread. This is why, if you are wrapping returned value in Flowable, you don't have to explicitly write *.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)* while creating observer. Whereas If you are using Flowable for network call(Single might be better because usually we need to emit only once), then you have to explicitly write .subscribeOn(Scheduler.io()) to run the call on a background thread.

Answer (score 2):

Room doesn't allow database operation on the Main thread unless you allow database on the main thread with `allowMainThreadQueries()`.

```
MyApp.database = Room.databaseBuilder(this,AppDatabase::class.java,"MyDatabase")
                     .allowMainThreadQueries()
                     .build()
```

Comment: No, If you are wrapping your return type in `LiveData` you don't need to set `.allowMainThreadQueries()`, queries are run asynchronously on a background thread with `LiveData`

Comment: That's what I did :  @Query("SELECT * FROM somedata")
    fun loadAllData(): LiveData<List<SomeData>>

Comment: @LieForBananas, I agree about "asynchronously" but I'm not sure on the "on a background thread". Could you please provide us document or source code about "on a background thread"?

Comment: @Bananadroid you mean you want to know exactly how it's done in the source code, or you want a document that confirms that's it's done on the background thread?

Comment: @LieForBananas any of those is enough. Thank you.

Comment: @Bananadroid Sure, no problem, here is a small quote from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata):  
**Room generates all the necessary code to update the LiveData object when a database is updated. The generated code runs the query asynchronously on a background thread when needed.**

Comment: @LieForBananas Thank you so much for pointing it out! I missed it.
But, I have a question about "when needed". Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Bananadroid well, I think one example may be if the user specifies `allowMainThreadQueries()` then it's not needed, otherwise it's on a background thread. There may be other cases, but I can't think of anything at the moment.

Comment: @LieForBananas That's ok. Thank you!

Comment: If allowMainThreadQueries is set, LiveData starts performing queries on main thread.